# Data table where some columns are scrollable horizontal and the whole table scrollable vertical with sticky headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

I am asked to build a table with a few (horizontal) scrollable columns. As the table can have hundreds of rows, the whole table should be scrollable as well within a given container. The header row should stay in its place meanwhile and not be scrollable.

My basic version so far is [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/L4d3v3wt/6/)

The current problem is, that I have the non-scrollable columns position:fixed and so they are not scrollable within the overflow container.

```
.wrapper {  /* does not work */
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
} 

.alldates {
    width: 225px;
    overflow: auto;  
    margin-left:160px;
}

.weekday {
    position:fixed;
    width:40px;
    left:0;
}
.date {
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    left:52px;
}
...
```

[image]

It would also be possible to use a jQuery plugin for this, if someone knows one.